# Should "unknown" values be included in probability calculation?

Tags: probability, statistics

When calculating Joint, Marginal, and Conditional probabilities with "unknown" values like the table below, should they be included in the totals? or are they ignored when calculating the probabilities?

For example, what is the probability that the offender is at least 18 if we known the victim was at least 18 (I'm not asking for the specific answer to this question but rather the inclusion/exclusion of the Unknown)?

Would it be
$$P = \frac{Joint Probability}{Marginal Probability} = \frac{\frac{4870}{5924}}{\frac{5180}{5924}} = \frac{.82}{.87} = .94$$
Or
$$P = \frac{Joint Probability}{Marginal Probability} = \frac{\frac{4870}{6434}}{\frac{5579}{6434}} = \frac{.76}{.87} = .87$$

[image]

Comment: Since you don't **know** whether the "unknowns" fit the criteria or not, you **can't** include those.  But I don't see where you got either of those denominators.  Not counting the "unknowns" there are 310+ 4870= 5180 cases in which the victim is "at least 18".

Comment: @user247327 I was showing the calculation for the probability for the denominator. Wouldn't it be 5180 / 5924? So .87 for the denominator in the first equation. Unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: My question was where did you get the "5924"?

Comment: @user247327 Ahh, that is the total for the set not including the "unknowns" (148+310+596+4870). I guess it's unnecessary to put it in the equation though?

Comment: That's incorrect then.  You specifically said "if we know the victim was at least 18".  There are only 310+ 4870= 5180 such cases.

Comment: @user247327 I was calculating (joint probability)/(marginal probability). So if I use P = 4870/5180, isn't the answer still the same at .94?